# Remove Items From Microsoft Access Add-In Manager List

Tags: ms-access, add-in

I've uninstalled several Add-Ins within Microsoft Access. And while these Add-Ins are truly uninstalled... The names of the Add-Ins still remain within the available Add-Ins drop down as shown: 
[image: MS Access Add-In Menu]

I've scoured the internet looking for a way to clear this list... all I can find are articles on how to "Uninstall" add-ins... which I've done... but this did not clear the list for me.

Of note is the fact that I am running to versions of Access  parallel to each other (2013 and 2010) on the same machine and am wondering if this could be the culprit as to why the list is not clearing? Does anyone know where this list is being cached so that I can manually clear it... Maybe the registry? I really do not want to have to re-install Access... but this is really getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 0):

I really hate to answer my own question... but as I was asking this question the thought occurred to me that it was the Registry where I needed to clear this list... thus you see my final question as referring to the registry.

Sure enough, after locating the registry location (Which was not easy as from what I gathered depends not only your Operating System... but also whether are running a 32 or 64 bit version of Access.) As a side note I am really curious if there is a list somewhere of all the possible locations?

As earlier mentioned I am running two versions parallel Access 2013 64 bit and Access 2010 32 bit... the list I needed clearing was the 2013 version so the location was: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Menu Add-Ins`

Comment: You've gotten no other love here, but it's not a bad thing to answer your own question. It's actually encouraged if you manage to find it, as it can be helpful to the next person. Your question/answer, unfortunately, didn't help me, but I was hoping there might be something useful for me here. Oh well, back to the Google results...

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that 'Unistalling' from the add-in Manager works for me.  When opening the add-in manager, your add-in does not have an 'X' on the left hand side of it.  Highlight your add-in, click Install, the 'X' shows up, now click Uninstall, and the 'X; goes away.  Close the add-in manager, and now your add-in items have been removed.

Comment: that is great if the addin was properly installed. In case of install failure, you're stuck with error messages and impossibility to use the procedure you describe.